# Generics type : not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

I got this error when coding. Can anyone explain to me why is it not applicable and how to fix it. Thanks a lot in advance!

> Error: The method linSearch(T[], T) in the type SearchTools12 is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int[], int)

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class SearchTools12 {
public static int[] createSequence(int n){
    int[] a= new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i]=i+1;
    }
    return a;
}
public static <T> int linSearch (T[] a, T x){ 
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < a.length){
        if (x == a[i]) return i;
        i += 1;
    } 
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int n=30;
    int x=15;
    System.out.println(linSearch(createSequence(n), x));

}
}
```

Comment: I have no JDK in order to do a test, but I think that the right syntax to call your method is linSearch<Integer>(createSequence(n), x). Your method is declared as generic, you have to precise the type associated when you call it

Comment: Caution: `x == a[i]` will fail for most types which aren’t enum types.  In Java, `==` compares references, meaning it evaluates to true only if the operands are exactly the same object, instead of checking for equivalence.

Comment: by the way, there is no reason for `linSearch` to be generic -- a declaration of `public static int linSearch (Object[] a, Object x)` will accept the exact same possible arguments, and work the same way

Answer (score 4):

the reason for this is that `int` is a primitive type, which has a specific role in java so you cannot cast `int[]` to `T[]`. Instead of using the primitive type, you can use `Integer[]` and it should work fine. So you should change your `createSequence` method to

```
public static Integer[] createSequence(int n) {
    Integer[] a = new Integer[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: agree. And generally containers of type B are poor casteable (or not at all) to type B

Answer (score 0):

The `linSearch (T[] a, T x)` expects an array of `T`, but you are trying to pass an array of `int`. And the type of array `int[]` is not same as type of array `T[]`.

To do the trick, can try to change:

```
linSearch (T x, T... a) // vararg of generic T
```

Then call:

```
linSearch(x, createSequence(n))  // passing int[] to T...
```